# Way to Only Pass Second Template Parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, template-argument-deduction, default-arguments

So I have a template function which has a defaulted 2<sup>nd</sup> argument. It's 1<sup>st</sup> argument can be deduced, so something like:

```
template <typename F, typename S = int>
void foo(const F param)
```

This works fine in the general case, I'll just call `foo(bar)`. But in the case where I want to specify the second argument, I cannot do this: `foo<char>(bar)`, because `char` is taken as `F`. Obviously this isn't the case because `bar` isn't a `char`, so `F` should be deducible.

Is there a way that I can pass only one template argument here which will apply to `S`, still have `F` be deduced, and still default `S` in the general case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just reorder template arguments:

```
template <typename S = int, typename F>
void foo(const F param);
```

template can have default at any place. At the end, all template parameters should be provided, defaulted or deduced.

Comment: Maybe you could remark about the possibility to give a default value not only to trailing template parameters, unlike the situation with function arguments.

Comment: I've accepted this, but as is mentioned by the other comments, I'd appreciate a little bit of explanation of why this doesn't work for functions in contrast with what's going on with templates.

Comment: In both case, all parameters should be known at the end. template allows deduction whereas functions don't have a way to specify/deduce "later" parameters.